# How can I use await in ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

This is not a duplicate.I would like to be able to perform await in a constancy in my ejs file, but I have the famous error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in C:\Users\...\dashboard.ejs while compiling ejs`
Could you explain to me how it works and how I can fix my code? :

app.js

```js
  let ejsOptions = {
    // delimiter: '?', Adding this to tell you do NOT use this like I've seen in other docs, does not work for Express 4
    async: true
  };

  // We set out templating engine.
  app.engine("html", async (path, data, cb) => {
    try{
      let html = await ejs.renderFile(path, data, ejsOptions);
      cb(null, html);
    }catch (e){
      cb(e, '');
    }
  });


  app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {

    await renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", { perms: Discord.Permissions });
  });
```

dashboard.ejs :

```html
  <%
  let results;
 
    results = await bot.shard.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.cache.get('${guild.id}')`);
  
  console.log(results.id)

  if (results) {
     %>
    <a class="button is-success has-text-centered" href="/dashboard/<%= guild.id %>">Settings</a>
  <% } else { %>
    <a class="button is-primary has-text-centered" href="<%= `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${bot.user.id}&scope=bot&guild_id=${guild.id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(`${bot.config.domain}${bot.config.port == 80 ? "" : `:${bot.config.port}`}/callback`)}` %>">Invite</a>
  <% } 

    %>
   <% }); %>
<%- include("partials/footer") %>
</section>
```

I have tried many methods, but when I try to use 'if' 'else' no results appear.

Comment: EJS files aren't functions. The more important question is *why* you'd want to do this: templates are the wrong place for logic like this.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just need to grab that promise, and I have in up a forEach method that gives me "guild". This retrieves the user's guilds and it should check for each guild whether it exists or not. Is there any way to do this in the app.js? If yes, how

Comment: Don't render the template until you have the data for the template.

Comment: What do you mean by that @KevinB

Comment: @EthanBrunet await the shard.broadcastEval in the /dashboard route handler, not the ejs file. don't call renderTemplate until you have said data.

Comment: @KevinB except that the guild.id I get it in the template.

Comment: so get it from the other place.

Comment: @KevinB `user.guilds.forEach(guild => {` this is guild. How do I use the forEach if I put it in the app.js?

Comment: I can't dig through your code to find it for you.

Comment: @EthanBrunet You may want to take a step back for a moment. Templates should be pretty "dumb"; data should be prepared before rendering almost always. I see no loop, but handling multiple async requests is pretty well documented around the web.

Comment: @KevinB This is not the point. I could use all of this in the app.js, but then I wouldn't be able to list everything I'm supposed to get with the forEach, if I do it in the app.js instead of the template.

Comment: something in your code is passing that data *to* the template, the template isn't somehow just magically conjuring up that data.

Comment: @DaveNewton So I'm supposed to put all of my javascript including the forEach in my app.js

Comment: @EthanBrunet You're suggesting you can retrieve the data in a template, but not in the underlying JS. A template is just a template with embedded JavaScript; any JS *in* a template can run run *outside* a template.

Comment: @EthanBrunet That would certainly be my recommendation, yes.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, and through the res.render file I can send whatever I get from my forEach loop to my ejs file?

Comment: @EthanBrunet Again, I'd really recommend taking a quick step back: walking before running and all that. You might want to investigate some basics of the technologies you're using; it'll save a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare all render data needed by the template before rendering it. For your `results` example, it would be something like:

```
app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const results = await bot.shard.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.cache.get('${guild.id}')`);
    renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", { perms: Discord.Permissions, results });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you get resultes data before render ejs file like this.

**app.js**

```js
app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const data = await bot.shard.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.cache.get('${guild.id}')`);
    renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", { perms: Discord.Permissions, data });
});
```

**dashboard.ejs**

```js
.... your code.....

  if (data != undefined) || data != null) {
     %>
    <a class="button is-success has-text-centered" href="/dashboard/<%= guild.id %>">Settings</a>
  <% } else { %>
    <a class="button is-primary has-text-centered" href="<%= `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${bot.user.id}&scope=bot&guild_id=${guild.id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(`${bot.config.domain}${bot.config.port == 80 ? "" : `:${bot.config.port}`}/callback`)}` %>">Invite</a>
  <% } 

    %>
   <% }); %>
<%- include("partials/footer") %>
</section>
```

some changes according to requirement.!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get("/dashboard", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
    const results = await bot.shard.broadcastEval(`this.guilds.cache.get('${guild.id}')`);
//You need to add async true to use await inside ejs file 
    renderTemplate(res, req, "dashboard.ejs", { perms: Discord.Permissions, results }, {async : true });
});
```

Maybe this can help